# Makefile not deleting intermediate files

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

My `Makefile` is not deleting intermediate files. I've set `.INTERMEDIATE`. Here is my Makefile:

```
OBJECTS=prefixer.o stack.o
CFLAGS=-Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -g
LIBS=-lm
CC=gcc

prefixer : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o prefixer $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

prefixer.o : stack.h
    $(CC) -c prefixer.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
stack.o : stack.c stack.h
    $(CC) -c stack.c -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

.INTERMEDIATE: %.o

.PHONY: clean
clean : 
    -rm prefixer *.o
```

What is wrong with `.INTERMEDIATE`?

Comment: Side question: I don't know `.INTERMEDIATE`, but can I ask why you want to do this? Makefile is good so you can avoid rebuilding `.o` files the sources of which are untouched. If you want to rebuild everything every time, why not just use a script?

Comment: You miss the dependency `prefixer.c` -> `prefixer.o`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you mean? Its the second one `prefixer.o: stack.h ....`

Comment: yes, you should have `prefixer.o : prefixer.c stack.h` in your `Makefile` line 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Gnu make special targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) for role of `.INTERMEDIATE`

You probably mean

```
 .SECONDARY:  $(OBJECTS)
```

because I think that if you put `.INTERMEDIATE` then the objects will always be removed, and you probably don't want that. I don't think you can meaningfully put `%.o` as prerequisites of special targets.

I would suggest to keep the object files so you don't waste time recompiling them.

Running once `make -p` will teach you a lot about the rules that `make` knows about.

Using `remake -x`  (i.e. [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)) is very helpful, at least to debug complex `Makefile`-s. You could also use `make -d` but I find it too verbose.

You may want to use better builders than `make` e.g. [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html).

Comment: But that doesn't do anything, does it? What would `.SECONDARY $(OBJECTS)` do? I want to clean up the clutter in the directory and therefore using `.INTERMEDIATE`. Secondly, how would I let make recompile if a source has been modified? Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't do any special target tricks, the `*.o` are built and kept in the directory (because `make` does handle transitive dependencies), and `make` will recompile appropriately. Of course you need to give *source* -> *object* dependencies.

Comment: For some reason, when I change one of the source files, and run `make` again, it says `prefixer` is up to date.. When it isn't. What am I missing here? I thought this "feature" is default to `make` and does not require any extra commands.

Comment: According to http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html you _can_ use `%.o` as a prerequisite of the special target `.PRECIOUS`. `.PRECIOUS` acts just like `.SECONDARY` with small differences.

Answer (score 4):

The special target `.INTERMEDIATE` doesn't work with the `%` wildcard. Try this:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: stack.o prefixer.o
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `.INTERMEDIATE` is not supposed to delete the intermediate files if it already exists. This is from the documentation of gnu make:

> Intermediate files are remade using their rules just like all other files. But intermediate files are treated differently in two ways.
>
> The first difference is what happens if the intermediate file does not exist. If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won't bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.
>
> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed. Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also does not exist after make. make reports the deletion to you by printing a ‘rm -f’ command showing which file it is deleting.

So make sure there are no `*.o` in the directory before running make.